# IIS express error500.24 web api

Tags: c#, .net, xml, api, iis-express

I migrate an dotnet framework web api application from vs 2010 to 2019.
I want to use IIS express for developpement mode debug.
My application is built with a api back in dotnet framework 4.5 using xml and not json and a front in dotnet winform.

[image: error api rest]

[image: message html front]

[image: error front]

sorry for the french messages.

thanks a lot for your suggest.
I've been stuck with this for a week

Vincent

I tried to change the web.config, the applicationhost.config (in the user iis express directory and the .VS\config directory.
add modules to IIS manager

[image: IIS config]

Comment: Your client made a request to the server and got back a response which is very good.  Problem is the server got an error while processing the request.  Either the server didn't like a parameter in the request, didn't like a http header in the request, or got an exception while doing the processing.  Most likely the 3rd option.  I assume you are running on a new server and this is the 1st time you are running the request on the new server.  I would check the Event Viewer on the Server to see if there are any error when you ran the code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis Most people finished their migration more than a decade ago.

Comment: This is a old application witch run on VS server 2010 for the debug.

Comment: Now we want to run the web api server on IIS express on VS2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help
I have tried
validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"

and it worked only when I deleted the lines created in the applicationhost.config (but it's not a solution)
we finally found: the problem was that I modified the .csproj file; but the file used for the user configuration is the .csproj.user.
It is modified with the "property" tab of VS.
I had seen it in a post for an mvc web application, since we are using an api, I thought it was different because it is an api.....
My colleague showed me the options in the panel... and now it works!!!!

[[image: configuration]]You have to modify in properties :
anonymous authentication : disable
windows authentication : enable
pipiline mode : classic
and that's all

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line from your web.config,

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

Or,
as Described in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/validation);

- Your application's Web.config file specifies "identity
  impersonate='true'".

> In IIS 7 Integrated mode, client impersonation is not available in
> some early request processing stages. Therefore, IIS will generate the
> migration error message. If your ASP.NET Web application impersonates
> client credentials (most common with intranet scenarios), you may want
> to set the validateIntegratedModeConfiguration attribute to false.

Add this section to your config to overcome this issue,

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure all the following .NET modules are installed.

1. .NET SDK 6.0.100
2. .NET Runtime 6.0.0
3. .NET hosting 6.0.0
   note that the above are the current versions the versions may differ.
   also change the version of .config files by running as Administrator whether you open the .json on Notepad or your IDE.
   make sure your Internet Information Services is up to date and have selected all features on IIS

Comment: If you read carefully, this is an ASP.NET web app, not ASP.NET Core.

Comment: If you want to say the .net core 6, I am on a .net framework 4.5 application use in production and if we migrate to VS 2019 it is not planished to migrate from .net framework 4 to .net core 6